# Add item to the table from dictonary when key is not known ios,swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I have retrieved data from firebase and stored it in a dictionary.

it looks somewhat like this:

> ["kmFcP8NxxnpqZ8rcya9amPfAFFzSz1": xyz@gmail.com,
> "75M2moeHxxXHSXq09jki0sl7hiEbd2": xyz@gmail.com,
> "iX8othUunxxxUuCDpkIjO7rRBnvu32": xyz@gmail.com]

now I want to add these values in a UiTableView. The cell only contains a label on which I have to show these values.

if the keys wouldn't have been random and maybe had a name, suppose "name" .I could have done something like this

```
cell.label.text = dict[indexpath.row]["name"] as! String
```

but since the keys are random, how can I do it?

Comment: You can iterate through all elements instead of receiving them by name

Comment: Does your firebase document really contain a map field where the field name is the same as the field contents?  What is the point of that data structure? Why have you created a dictionary when you could just use an array of strings?  Perhaps show the code where you load from firebase?

Comment: made an edit, that was the old data, see the updated one.

Comment: The `Dictionary` type has a property `values`

Comment: I'm with Joakim here. Are you asking [how to get all values from a dictionary in Swift?](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+get+all+values+from+dictionary)

Comment: Yes, with the updated data, you can use the `values` array, but it still seems like you aren't loading the data from Firestore in a very useful way. Firestore for Swift supports Codable so you can very easily have an array of structs from your data.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get all keys in a separate array because dictionary is hashable and indexPath won't work in it. for that you can do

```
let keys = dictionary.keys()
```

In `numberOfItems in section` use return `keys.count`

Later in `cellForRowAt indexPath` you can acheive something like this

```
cell.label.text = dict[keys[indexpath.row]] as! String
```

What it'll do is to find the key associated to the row in dictionary. and it is completely dynamic